# php how to store monday to friday of the next 6 months begin from tomorrow in an array

Tags: php, html

I am making a page to let the clients choose a date for an appointment, so I need to build a list of the dates like this :
[image]

- always begin from tomorrow, end by 6 months
- always from Mondy to Saturday, no Sunday
- the day of the week need to be in chinese, like "Monday" is "星期一", but the timezone is in France

Here is the php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

$tomorrow = date("Y年m月d日 l", time() + 86400);
$end = date("Y年m月d日 l", time() + 86400 * 7); // just 7 days for a try 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($tomorrow, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    echo $date . '<br/>';
}
```

This code is not working. 
I need to build an array, which store all the dates of next 6 months, begin from tomorrow, without Sunday, the days need to be in chinese and the timezone needs to be in Europe, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think strtotime and array_push is what you are looking for. Try this:

```
$curDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 months +1 day'));

$myArr = array();
while ($endDate >= $curDate) {
    if (date('w', strtotime($curDate)) !== '0') array_push($myArr, $curDate);
    $curDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curDate . " +1 days"));
}

var_dump($myArr);
```

For the Options, create an array from sunday to saturday.

```
$weekdays = array('Sunday', ..., 'Saturday');
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($curDate)) . ' ' . $weekdays[date('w', strtotime($curDate))];
```

Comment: your code works well, except the weekdays, I do a `for` to loop $myArr to `echo` in the `<option>` of `<select>` tag, in this case, `$curDate` is the final date + 1, it' a Wensday, so it gives a fixed 3 to `$weekdays`, I have the correct dates but always Wensday, how to give the `$weekdays` the correct index?

Comment: It's done! I add weekdays every time it push a date in $myArr, now I have what I want as in the first image !